# How to detect if a character from a string is upper or lower case?

Tags: string, delphi, parsing, delphi-7

I'm expanding a class of mine for storing generic size strings to allow more flexible values for user input. For example, my prior version of this class was strict and allowed only the format of `2x3` or `9x12`. But now I'm making it so it can support values such as `2 x 3` or `9 X 12` and automatically maintain the original user's formatting if the values get changed.

The real question I'm trying to figure out is just how to detect if one character from a string is either upper or lower case? Because I have to detect case sensitivity. If the deliminator is 'x' (lowercase) and the user inputs 'X' (uppercase) inside the value, and case sensitivity is turned off, I need to be able to find the opposite-case as well.

I mean, the `Pos()` function is case sensitive...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Delphi 7 has UpperCase() and LowerCase() functions for strings. There's also UpCase() for characters.

If I want to search for a substring within another string case insensitively, I do this:

```
if Pos('needle', LowerCase(hayStack)) > 0 then
```

You simply use lower case string literals (or constants) and apply the lowercase function on the string before the search. If you'll be doing a lot of searches, it makes sense to convert just once into a temp variable.

Here's your case:

```
a := '2 x 3';  // Lowercase x
b := '9 X 12'; // Upper case X

x := Pos('x', LowerCase(a)); // x = 3
x := Pos('x', LowerCase(b)); // x = 3
```

To see if a character is upper or lower, simply compare it against the UpCase version of it:

```
a := 'A';
b := 'b';

upper := a = UpCase(a); // True
upper := b = UpCase(b); // False
```

Comment: Great "finding the needle in the haystack" example :P and it looks like that's also the much easier approach to doing this too. No parsing involved in this case, just 1) Remove spaces, 2) Locate deliminator, 3) Get text before and after deliminator, and 4) Try to convert left and right text into numbers. My previous approach was looping char by char.

Comment: I stole the needle/haystack analogy from PHP docs. It's better than foo/bar in this case. :)

Answer (score 9):

try using these functions (which are part of the [Character](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Character) unit)

- [Character.TCharacter.IsUpper](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Character.TCharacter.IsUpper)
- [Character.TCharacter.IsLower](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Character.TCharacter.IsLower)
- [`IsLower`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Character.IsLower)
- [`IsUpper`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/Character.IsUpper)

**UPDATE**

For ansi versions of delphi you can use the [`GetStringTypeEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318118%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) functions to fill a list with each ansi character type information. and thne compare the result of each element against the $0001(Upper Case) or $0002(Lower Case) values.

```
uses
  Windows,
  SysUtils;

Var
  LAnsiChars: array [AnsiChar] of Word;

procedure FillCharList;
var
  lpSrcStr: AnsiChar;
  lpCharType: Word;
begin
  for lpSrcStr := Low(AnsiChar) to High(AnsiChar) do
  begin
    lpCharType := 0;
    GetStringTypeExA(LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, CT_CTYPE1, @lpSrcStr, SizeOf(lpSrcStr), lpCharType);
    LAnsiChars[lpSrcStr] := lpCharType;
  end;
end;

function CharIsLower(const C: AnsiChar): Boolean;
const
  C1_LOWER  = $0002;
begin
  Result := (LAnsiChars[C] and C1_LOWER) <> 0;
end;

function CharIsUpper(const C: AnsiChar): Boolean;
const
  C1_UPPER  = $0001;
begin
  Result := (LAnsiChars[C] and C1_UPPER) <> 0;
end;

begin
  try
    FillCharList;
    Writeln(CharIsUpper('a'));
    Writeln(CharIsUpper('A'));
    Writeln(CharIsLower('a'));
    Writeln(CharIsLower('A'));
  except
    on E:Exception do
      Writeln(E.Classname, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
  Readln;
end.
```

Comment: Character... Doesn't seem to be found in Delphi 7 - is this in a newer version? (I forgot to tag it delphi-7)

Comment: Please add always your delphi version.

Comment: +1, Or you might try to use [IsCharLower](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647484%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [IsCharUpper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647485%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) for determining the char case but this is based on the locale settings.

Answer (score 5):

```
   if myChar in ['A'..'Z'] then
    begin
      // uppercase
    end
   else
      if myChar in ['a'..'z'] then
      begin
        // lowercase
      end
      else
        begin
          // not an alpha char
        end;
```

..or D2009 on..

```
   if charInSet(myChar,['A'..'Z']) then
   begin
      // uppercase
   end
   else
     if charInSet(myChar,['a'..'z']) then
     begin
       // lowercase
     end
     else
        begin
          // not an alpha char
        end;
```

Comment: Good answer, and it means I have to loop through each character and keep track of `if (HasL) and (not HasD) then ... else if (HasL) and (HasD) and (not HasR) then ... ` and so on... But that's overall how I should do it anyway :D

Answer (score 1):

The JCL has routines for this in the JclStrings unit, eg CharIsUpper and CharIsLower. SHould work in Delphi 7.

Answer (score 1):

`AnsiPos()` is not case-sensitive. You can also force upper or lower case, irrespective of what the user enters using `UpperCase()` and `LowerCase()`.

Just throwing this out there since you may find it far more simple than the other (very good) answers.

Comment: I thought of forcing it, but our user community is very insistent on doing things their way :P

Comment: You don't have to force the format it's entered or stored in, only the format used behind the scenes to operate on the values!